# How to change color of an image button when the mouse is over it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, material-design-in-xaml

I have created a `Button` with an image that you can see below:

[image: Button with gear image.]

I used the following XAML code to create this `Button`:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Padding="0"
        ToolTip="Settings" Width="30"
        IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ControlsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cog" Width="32" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
            <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
    </materialDesign:PackIcon>
</Button>
```

My problem is that the icon color is changed only when the mouse is over the icon, not the `Button`. I want it to change color when the mouse is over the `Button`.

How can I fix it in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) binding to refer to the `IsMouseOver` property of the parent `Button`.

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```